# R: Running sum of changed column values within groups

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection(
    "ID DATE    UNIT
100 1/5/2005    4
100 2/6/2006    4
100 3/7/2007    5
100 4/7/2008    5
100 5/9/2009    6
101 1/5/2005    1
101 2/6/2006    1
101 3/7/2007    1
101 4/7/2008    1
102 1/3/2010    3
102 4/5/2010    4
102 5/9/2011    3
102 6/7/2011    5
102 10/10/2012  5
103 1/5/2005    1
103 1/6/2010    2"),header=TRUE)
```

I want to group by ID, sort each group by DATE, and create another column that is a running count of the number of times the UNIT variable has changed for each given ID variable.  So I want an output that looks like this:

```
ID  DATE    UNIT    CHANGES
100 1/5/2005    4   0
100 2/6/2006    4   0
100 3/7/2007    5   1
100 4/7/2008    5   1
100 5/9/2009    6   2
101 1/5/2005    1   0
101 2/6/2006    1   0
101 3/7/2007    1   0
101 4/7/2008    1   0
102 1/3/2010    3   0
102 4/5/2010    4   1
102 5/9/2011    3   2
102 6/7/2011    5   3
102 10/10/2012  5   3
103 1/5/2005    1   0
103 1/6/2010    2   1
```

Comment: COOL THANKS!  Not that it matters that much, but how hard would it be to do without dplyer?  Probably too much of a pain to do it with apply functions and stock?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this in base R, using `order` to sort the observations and `ave` to compute the grouped values:

```
df$DATE <- as.Date(df$DATE, "%m/%d/%Y")
df <- df[order(df$ID, df$DATE),]
df$CHANGES <- ave(df$UNIT, df$ID, FUN=function(x) c(0, cumsum(diff(x) != 0)))
df
#     ID       DATE UNIT CHANGES
# 1  100 2005-01-05    4       0
# 2  100 2006-02-06    4       0
# 3  100 2007-03-07    5       1
# 4  100 2008-04-07    5       1
# 5  100 2009-05-09    6       2
# 6  101 2005-01-05    1       0
# 7  101 2006-02-06    1       0
# 8  101 2007-03-07    1       0
# 9  101 2008-04-07    1       0
# 10 102 2010-01-03    3       0
# 11 102 2010-04-05    4       1
# 12 102 2011-05-09    3       2
# 13 102 2011-06-07    5       3
# 14 102 2012-10-10    5       3
# 15 103 2005-01-05    1       0
# 16 103 2010-01-06    2       1
```

Comment: Wow thanks josilbr.  I'm trying to understand your code and I realize I've never seen the c() used as a function definition.  Is there name for this or is this explained somewhere? BTW Love the Analytics Edge course.

Comment: Glad you enjoyed the course! As described in [this tutorial](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector), `c` creates vectors from its arguments. Basically `cumsum(diff(x) != 0)` is the number of changes in `x` counting from the second index, but we also want to return a 0 value for the first index so we return `c(0, cumsum(diff(x) != 0))`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`.

First I'm converting your DATE column to a date, assuming it's in format m/d/y (if not, change the `"%m/%d/%Y"` to `"%d/%m/%Y"`):

```
df$DATE <- as.Date(df$DATE, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Now the code:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
       arrange(DATE) %>% 
       mutate(CHANGES=c(0,cumsum(na.omit(UNIT!=lag(UNIT,1)))))
```